# Firebase rules anonymous and authentificated

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to write a rule for my Firebase users.

My goal is to have a  rule to allow  write/read in the database for:

1. **anonymous** users authentificated through [Firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) which are  temporary anonymous accounts
2. **authenticated** users with email and password.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart), you can give everyone who is signed in access to your entire database with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "auth.uid !== null"
  }
}
```

In [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) you can accomplish the same with these rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that both of these samples come from the Firebase documentation, so I highly recommend that you spend some time studying that.

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough (I got a terrible -4). I am using Firebase auth.  User can be anonymously authentificated, which is not the same as anyone and authentificated users. What I am trying to achieve is to let those two type of users to read/write and reject others.

Comment: I updated my answer to do that. Note that both snippets again are easy to find by reading the relevant Firebase documentation that I linked.

Comment: I though I had to do a logical test on both authentficated and anonymous.  thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Users who sign in anonymously are also authenticated, they're just not identified.

Answer (score 20):

I don't agree with accepted answer. If user is authenticated as Anonymous, he has UID anyway so checking if it is null doesn't solve the problem.

'auth' variable has 'provider' property so all you have to do to check if user is authenticated with email and password or anonymously is this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.provider != 'anonymous'",
    ".write": "auth.provider != 'anonymous'"
  }
}
```

Here is more from documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#variables

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, thank you!

Comment: If you don't want to allow anonymous users access to the data, you should not enable anonymous authentication in the Firebase console. In this case, the OP explicitly asks to allow access to their data by users that are anonymously authenticated.

Comment: If anyone is looking for Firestore, it would be `request.auth.sign_in_provider != 'anonymous'` ([ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth))

Comment: It is `request.auth.token.firebase.sign_in_provider != 'anonymous'` now.

Comment: @MehmetEsen [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#variables) says both are valid