# Can I restrict users who're authenticated anonymously in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

In firebase app, which have two sign-in options Google sign-in and Anonymous sign-in. I would like to write security rules for both but some restriction for anonymous like write access.

**The Question is, **How do I identity if a user is authenticated anonymously or google sign-in?
How to distinguish between security rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Variables](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#variables)

You can distinguish between authenticated and anonymous users using variables.

Here's an example that allows read and write as far as the user isn't anonymous.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.provider != 'anonymous'",
    ".write": "auth.provider != 'anonymous'"
  }
}
```

Also, see [Firebase rules anonymous and authentificated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52588169/22152755).